# EAGLE 9.4.1 How do I autoroute a range of signals?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, test-equipment, autorouter

I have a board with three 32 input analog multiplexers, along with more components, connected to a 96 way DIN connector. How do I manually tell the autorouter to select only the muxers signals? I tried "AUTO U1_S[1..32]" for the first muxer but apparently eagle bugs out and select only up to U1_S3, ignoring it is actually 32 instead of 3.

I tried to select them from the design manager but it doesn't seem to care at all an routes the whole board.

It is a bug or a feature and I'm doing it wrong? I know I can manually click all 96 wires but... I would have to do it every single time and that's not cool.

All three muxers follow the same naming schema, as U1_S1..U1_S32, U2_S1..U1_S32..., etc

Ignore the fact that the autorouter is evil, that it creates weird traces and so.. but routing a 96way 3 row DIN connector is quite tricky for me and the autorouter already does the 100% of the board, but I'd like to try "guiding" it selectively.

I'm learning how to do it on the go, so please be kind. Also I'm aware that this is not a DIL atmega board with headers. If I need to write down all 96 nets and copy and paste from notepad...that's ok too but if there's a more human friendly obscure way the better.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See HELP AUTO for more information on what I'm about to describe. The easiest way to get those traces routed, would be to type the following into the command line:

```
AUTO U1_S* U2_S* U3_S*
```

Followed by the Enter key. The asterisk is a wildcard character that would pick up net names 1-32.

I encourage you to visit the Autodesk Forums where you can get help tailored to EAGLE.

Let me know if there's anything else I can do for you.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: In a similar topic.... 
- How do I select a subset of those nets? Is not implemented yet? I think the bus suffixing schema of [x..x] would be just fine for the autorouter.
- Is there a chance I could mouse-drag select nets from the board layout for the autorouter for those times where you clustered a circuit and it has different net names. I know I could rename them and prefix them with a specific name but....I think that could come in handy too